# Как сделать ветки ответов бота в ВК?

Tags: python, vkontakte-api

Хочу сделать бота для Вк, но ввиду своего маленького опыта работы в vk_api не могу сделать ветвь диалога. Пример привожу для команды казино

````
```
def cas():
    for event in longpoll.listen():
            if event.type == VkBotEventType.MESSAGE_NEW:
                kf = random.randint(0,5)
                vk.messages.send(
                peer_id=peer_id,
                message='Сколько хотите ставить?',
                random_id=get_random_id(),
                )      
                if text.lower() == text.lower():
                    text.lower=int(text.lower())
                    if kf==0:
                        vk.messages.send(
                            peer_id=peer_id,
                            message='Вы проиграли!',
                            random_id=get_random_id(),
                            )
                    elif kf==1:
                        vk.messages.send(
                            peer_id=peer_id,
                            message='Ваша ставка сохранилась!',
                            random_id=get_random_id(),
                        )
                    elif kf==2:
                        vk.messages.send(
                            peer_id=peer_id,
                            message='Вы выиграли! Коэффицент: 2х. Баланс: '+text.lower()*2,
                            random_id=get_random_id(),
                            )
                    elif kf==3:
                        vk.messages.send(
                            peer_id=peer_id,
                            message='Вы выиграли! Коэффицент: 3х. Баланс: '+text.lower()*3,
                            random_id=get_random_id(),
                            )
                    elif kf==4:
                        vk.messages.send(
                            peer_id=peer_id,
                            message='Вы выиграли! Коэффицент: 4х. Баланс: '+text.lower()*4,
                            random_id=get_random_id(),
                            )
                elif kf==5:
                        vk.messages.send(
                            peer_id=peer_id,
                            message='Вы выиграли! Коэффицент: 2х. Баланс: '+text.lower()*5,
                            random_id=get_random_id(),
                            )
```
````

Comment: Что такое "ветвь диалога"? Разное сообщение на разное значение kf?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В таком случае, Вам каждый раз придётся смотреть события через `for event in longpoll.listen()`, когда нужно получить ответ, иначе код выполнится без участия пользователя.

Также, убедитесь, что код будет работать для всех пользователей индивидуально и одновременно (Не нужно будет ожидать, пока ответит др. пользователь)

Код:

```
def is_digit(str): #Проверка: Можно ли str перевести в int
    if str is int():
        print("A str must be specified. Given an int.")
    elif str not is int():
        if string.isdigit():
            return True
        else:
            try:
                float(string)
                return True
            except ValueError:
                return False

def cas():

    id = event.user_id
    vk.messages.send(
        peer_id=peer_id,
        message='Сколько хотите ставить?',
        random_id=get_random_id(),
        )

    a = True

    while a == True:
        try:

            for event in longpoll.listen():
                if event.type == VkBotEventType.MESSAGE_NEW:
                    if event.to_me:
                        new_id = event.user_id
                        if new_id == id:
                            msg = event.text.lower()
                            if is_digit(msg) == False:
                                vk.messages.send(
                                    peer_id=peer_id,
                                    message='Указана неверная сумма ставки.',
                                    random_id=get_random_id()
                                    )
                            if is_digit(msg) == True:
                                kf = random.randint(0, 5)
                                if kf==0:
                                    vk.messages.send(
                                        peer_id=peer_id,
                                        message='Вы проиграли!',
                                        random_id=get_random_id(),
                                        )
                                elif kf==1:
                                    vk.messages.send(
                                        peer_id=peer_id,
                                        message='Ваша ставка сохранилась!',
                                        random_id=get_random_id(),
                                    )
                                elif kf==2:
                                    vk.messages.send(
                                        peer_id=peer_id,
                                        message='Вы выиграли! Коэффицент: 2х. Баланс: '+str(int(msg.lower())*2),
                                        random_id=get_random_id(),
                                        )
                                elif kf==3:
                                    vk.messages.send(
                                        peer_id=peer_id,
                                        message='Вы выиграли! Коэффицент: 3х. Баланс: '+str(int(msg.lower())*3),
                                        random_id=get_random_id(),
                                        )
                                elif kf==4:
                                    vk.messages.send(
                                        peer_id=peer_id,
                                        message='Вы выиграли! Коэффицент: 4х. Баланс: '+str(int(msg.lower())*4),
                                        random_id=get_random_id(),
                                        )
                                elif kf==5:
                                    vk.messages.send(
                                        peer_id=peer_id,
                                        message='Вы выиграли! Коэффицент: 2х. Баланс: '+str(int(msg.lower())*5),
                                        random_id=get_random_id(),
                                        )
                            elif is_digit(msg) == False:
                                vk.messages.send(
                                    peer_id=peer_id,
                                    message='Указана неверная сумма ставки.',
                                    random_id=get_radnom_id()
                                    )

                                a = False
                                break
                                

        except Exception as error:
            print(error)
```